# CPU Usage and heartbeats

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, cpu-usage

I've built a network layer that uses the SAEA socket commands to process multiple connections for an IOC container. This network layer uses a form of heartbeat that informs servers what topics the client is interested in.

My problem is that sometimes one of the processes running on top of the network layer hogs the CPU. This prevents the heartbeat from being called in a timely manner, and the server will see the subscriptions coming down from the client. I'm using System.Threading.Timer to run the heartbeat sending.

It turns out the offending process is mathematical calculation, not IO bound (my colleague preloads the data from a DB, which miraculously doesn't jam up the network.) He's using a Parallel.For loop to do the calculation, and you can see CPU usage jumping when it hits the loop.

I've tried a couple of things, with no luck:

1. Simply reduce the MaxDegreeOfParallelism on the loop.
2. Add a scheduler with a lower priority, like this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2011/01/29/how-to-schedule-task-on-different-thread-priority.aspx

What are some other strategies for making sure the heartbeat goes out? It really isn't much work in comparison to the math function that is eating up the CPU.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of issues priorities were meant to solve -- try that first.

Comment: This is more likely to be a hog-the-threadpool problem, you could tinker with ThreadPool.SetMinThreads().  Then again, if it is this critical then gen#2 garbage collections and page file thrashing ought to worry you as well.

Comment: The calculation is not an ongoing thing. It only needs to run once a day.

Cory - that is what I've tried. I thought that simply running the calculation on a lower priority would allow the heartbeat to take it's CPU slice when required.